# Extra argument 'method' in call

Tags: alamofire, swift3

Getting error while calling Alamofire request method in the latest version(4.0.0).

The syntax is:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .post, parameters: requestParams, encoding: .JSON, headers: [:])
```

the type of requestParam is [String:Any]

Comment: Did you try: `Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: requestParams, encoding: .JSON, headers: [:])`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I got the issue, I have to use JSONEncoding.default instead of .JSON, so the new syntax is

```
Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .post, parameters: requestParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
```

Comment: Not fixed for me, I have written the same code for this :(

Comment: Now it gives for method argument post

Comment: it's working for me i have passed headers parameter with type HTTPHeaders.hope this will wok for you.

Comment: I really think netiggers answer should be the accepted one. The underlying problem here is a red herring error message when a parameter has the wrong type.

Answer (score 50):

I can only refer you to: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1508#issuecomment-246207682

Basically, if one of your parameters is of the wrong type, the swift compiler will assume you're using `request(urlRequest:URLRequestConvertible)` and then, the `method` is an `extra argument`

Go over that parameters again and make sure all is of correct type (`Parameters?`, `ParameterEncoding`, and `HTTPHeaders`)

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue the value of ParameterEncoding was wrong, I have to use JSONEncoding.default instead of .JSON .

Comment: This was what caused it to me , I used parameters as string instead of [String:String]

Comment: Your explanation is what people need. not a dumb response, "do this ...", Thanks!

Comment: My first parameter was broken. I needed to change the `let urlString = "host"` to `static let urlString = "host"` because the `urlString` variable was attached to the class and I was writing a class function

Comment: Thumbs up. One of the best answers on SO!

Comment: This was my problem. The headers dictionary in my case, was actually [ String : Any ] when I thought it was [ String : String ] (HttpHeaders is just an alias for that). As soon as I forced the bad value to String it compiled. I was storing a token in userDefaults, and when I retrieved it I used object(forKey:) not string(forKey:).

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same issue, the problem is at parameters type, it should be of type [String: Any]. After I made this change, it worked for me.

```
 Alamofire.request(youUrl, method: .post, parameters: param as? [String: Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
                .responseJSON { response in
```

Comment: Yes, Some Time we need to define the param.

Answer (score 10):

It means that some of the parameters type are wrong, check that you are sending these values:

```
url: String
method: HTTPMethod  (E.g: .post)
parameters: [String:Any]
encoding: ParameterEncoding  (E.g: JSONEncoding.default)
headers: [String: String]
```

Comment: solved my problem, thank you. I don't know why swift does't show errors more clearly.

Comment: Remember put the correct type of data and avoid using nil!

Answer (score 10):

Updated for Swift 3:

```
let requestString = "https://thawing-inlet-46474.herokuapp.com/charge.php"
        let params = ["stripeToken": token.tokenId, "amount": "200", "currency": "usd", "description": "testRun"]

        Alamofire.request(requestString,method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                if response.result.value != nil{
                    print("response : \(response.result.value)")
                }
                break

            case .failure(_):
                print("Failure : \(response.result.error)")
                break

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your `parameters` is [String: Any]

i.e

```
let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]
```

**Not:**

```
let parameters : Parameter = ["foo": "bar"]
```

Comment: This was my mistake, I assumed it could be `[AnyHashable: Any]`.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting that error because of the wrong data types.

Parameters Type should be [String : Any] and parameters type shouldn't be an optional.

Header Type should be [String : String] or nil and header type shouldn't be an optional as well.

Hope it helps. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by ensuring my requestUrls are strings, and not URL types. Also I removed parameter arguments for when parameter was nil.

E.g.

`Alamofire.request(requestUrl, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default)`

Answer (score 3):

Almofire methods changed in Swift 3 as the following:

1. Reorder parameters (url then method type).
2. Change Encoding Enum to be "JSONEncoding.default" for example.

Comment: This was the recent issue for me. No hint that it was this, but it rather complained about the HTTPMethod. `.utf8` and similars won't do it, not even just `.default`. It has to be the long name: `JSONEncoding.default`

Answer (score 3):

This is a family of functions that are very similar, which makes the compiler think you're trying to use a different function. Double check that ALL of the arguments you're supplying are the CORRECT TYPE that is expected. For example I was passing [String:Any] for the variant with headers, which expected [String:String] and got the same error.

Comment: That's correct. I'm my case i was passing a [String] parameter instead of [String:String] and got the same error too.

Answer (score 3):

It is always because im using optional variables in any of the parameters

Comment: I solved my problem with this hint... Great... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem And try with all answer as previously post here, And then I got the solution and reason of this problem .

This is happened due to pass the wrong object parse in the request, and finally the solution --

`theJSONText` -- JSON string

`urlStr` -- URL string

```
 let urlEncoadedJson = theJSONText.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)
    let urls = NSURL(string:"urlStr\(urlEncoadedJson ?? "")")

let method: HTTPMethod = .get

Alamofire.request(urls! as URL, method: method, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):

            if response.result.value != nil
            { 
              // write your code here
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            if response.result.error != nil
            {
                print(response.result.error!) 
            }
            break
        }

    }
```

Note - There is no param in my URL .

Answer (score 1):

My problem was in optional parameters in the headers that were not unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: 
JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON 
{ response in

            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                print(response)
                break
            case .failure:
                print(Error.self)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just make sure all the parameters are in the correct format , most importantly the parameters must be in [String:Any] type array.