# Swift3: Extra argument method in call

Tags: json, request, swift3, alamofire

I am migrating my code from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3. Before it was working fine after migrating I am facing extra argument method in call error. Any help is appreciable. I am very new to the Swift language.

```
func POST(url _url: String, params: [String : AnyObject]) -> Future<JSON, NSError> {
    let request = Alamofire.request(self.buildAppUrl(_url), method:.post, parameters: [params], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.requestHeaders())  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra argument 'method' in call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571812/extra-argument-method-in-call)

Comment: parameters is not array it is dictionary.

Comment: @NiravD,Please can you elaborate the answer.

Comment: @srinitha It should be like `let request = Alamofire.request(self.buildAppUrl(_url), method:.post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: self.requestHeaders())` **Note:** Here params and  requestHeaders() must be `Dictionary`.

Comment: params is Dictionary and requestHeaders() is variable,still am getting same error @NiravD

Comment: @srinitha `self.requestHeaders()` is a function in your case, and what i'm saying is it should return Dictionary not some variable.