# Alamofire error String to pass data through json request

Tags: swift3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaqFR.png)

Give me your best solution in swift 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extra argument 'method' in call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571812/extra-argument-method-in-call)

Comment: plz share alamofire version

Comment: alamofire version 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

There must be problem with your parameters, so try like below code:

```
Alamofire.request(yourUrl, method: .post, parameters: param as? [String: Any], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:])
            .responseJSON { response in
```