# Failed to archive but success when build Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, archive

When I am building the app in simulator it works, but when I archive the project to upload, it's showing error

this is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Check by changing it like HTTPMethod.post

Comment: still not working

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571812/extra-argument-method-in-call

Answer (score 0):

In **encoding**. Try using `JSONEncoding.default` instead `URLEncoding.default`

Comment: its not the problem sir, still not working, btw thanks